# Unable to debug (potential) issues with "pyheif" or "libheif" libraries or in my script to convert heic files -> png

Tags: python, python-3.x, png, file-conversion, heic

wrote python script to convert a .heic image into .png to practise some coding

Step 1. Created the script

Step 2. Updated library to python3

Step 3. Ensured the installed Pyheif library is latest

Step 4. Upgraded Libheif to the latest version

Still the python script is not running and the issue I think is this -

'ffi.error: struct heif_decoding_options: wrong total size (cdef says 48, but C compiler says 72). fix it or use "...;" as the last field in the cdef for struct heif_decoding_options to make it flexible'

line 18 of the script (which was highlighted by VS_code) is -

```
 '''convert_heic_to_png('/Users/jash/Desktop/to_read-learn/Nerding_out/IMG_8712.heic', '/Users/jash/Desktop/Nerding_out/IMG_8712.png')'''
```

it is in python. any error in this? i am trying to take GPT's help too

Comment: Please click [edit] and format your question properly. Remove the backticks surrounding your code first. Then select each block of code with your mouse and click `{}` in the formatting toolbar to format as code - located at the top of the question beside **Bold** and *Italic*.

Comment: There are two open issues for this error: https://github.com/carsales/pyheif/issues/84 and https://github.com/carsales/pyheif/issues/92

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).